# SweetAlert2: change font size

Tags: sweetalert2

I'm trying to replace the sweetalert control with the new sweetalert2 but I've run into some doubts. Among them, I was able to change the width of the popup but not the height. It seems that the "height" property does not take effect.

```
 const { value: causas } = Swal.fire({
                            title: "Titulo",
                            text: "Este es el mensaje!",
                            input: 'select',
                            type: "warning",
                            showCancelButton: true,
                            confirmButtonText: "Confirmar!",
                            confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                            icon: 'warning',
                            cancelButtonText: "Cancelar!",
                            closeOnConfirm: true,
                            closeOnCancel: true,
                            width: 800,
                            height: 800,

                            inputOptions: {
                                'Causas': {
                                    cause1: 'c1',
                                    cause2: 'c2',
                                    cause3: 'c3',
                                    cause4: 'c4'
                                }
                            },
                            inputPlaceholder: 'Seleccione el item',
                            showCancelButton: true,
                            inputValidator: (value) => {
                                return new Promise((resolve) => {
                                    //if (value === 'oranges') {
                                    //    resolve()
                                    //} else {
                                    //    resolve('You need to select oranges :)')
                                    //}
                                })
                            }
                        })

                        if (fruit) {
                            Swal.fire(`You selected: ${fruit}`)
                        }
```

I also want to change the font size but I haven't found how to do it. Maybe I should generate/create a css file? Can you help me? Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

I just fixed it! I added the properties in the css file.

```
.swal2-popup {
    font-size: 14px !important;
}

.swal2-styled {
    padding: 10px 32px 10px 32px !important;
    margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px !important;
    width: 170px;
    height: 45px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In angular you can do this way.

For icon
`::ng-deep .swal2-icon { font-size: 8px; }`

for modal
`::ng-deep .swal2-popup { width: 20rem; }`

for text/title
`::ng-deep .swal2-title { font-size: 15px; }`